# The variable is not the same after return

Tags: python, return-value

I'm trying to put a text in a textbox getting text from a web page, this is my code:

```
def obtener_canales():
    for i in range (1,3):
        url = "http://arenavision.in/agenda"
        peticion = urllib2.Request(url, headers={'User-Agent' : "Magic Browser"})
        leemos_page = urllib2.urlopen(peticion)
        enlace_acestream = leemos_page.read()
        leemos_page.close()
    partido = enlace_acestream
    for item in partido.split("\n"):
        if "LIGA BBVA" in item:
              print item
```

with this code works fine, I get:

```
20/04/16 20:00 CET FUTBOL: DEPORTIVO DE LA CORUNA-FC BARCELONA (ESPAÑA/LIGA BBVA)/AV1/AV2/AV21/AV22<br/>
20/04/16 20:30 CET FUTBOL: SIMULCAST (ESPAÑA/LIGA BBVA)/AV6/AV26<br/>
20/04/16 20:45 CET FUTBOL: ATHLETIC CLUB-ATLETICO DE MADRID (ESPAÑA/LIGA BBVA)/AV9/AV10/AV29/AV30<br/>
20/04/16 20:45 CET FUTBOL: SPORTING GIJON-SEVILLA (ESPAÑA/LIGA BBVA)/AV11/AV12/AV31/AV32<br/>
20/04/16 22:00 CET FUTBOL: REAL MADRID-VILLARREAL (ESPAÑA/LIGA BBVA)/AV3/AV4/AV23/AV24<br/>
21/04/16 20:00 CET FUTBOL: REAL SOCIEDAD-GETAFE (ESPAÑA/LIGA BBVA)/AV5/AV25<br/>
21/04/16 21:00 CET FUTBOL: GRANADA-LEVANTE (ESPAÑA/LIGA BBVA)/AV1/AV2/AV21/AV22<br/>
22/04/16 21:00 CET FUTBOL: LAS PALMAS-ESPANYOL (ESPAÑA/LIGA BBVA)/AV1/AV2/AV21/AV22<br/>
23/04/16 16:00 CET FUTBOL: RAYO VALLECANO-REAL MADRID (ESPAÑA/LIGA BBVA)/AV1/AV2/AV21/AV22<br/>
23/04/16 18:15 CET FUTBOL: ATLETICO DE MADRID-MALAGA (ESPAÑA/LIGA BBVA)/AV1/AV2/AV21/AV22<br/>
23/04/16 20:30 CET FUTBOL: FC BARCELONA-SPORTING GIJON (ESPAÑA/LIGA BBVA)/AV3/AV4/AV23/AV24<br/>
23/04/16 22:05 CET FUTBOL: EIBAR-DEPORTIVO DE LA CORUNA (ESPAÑA/LIGA BBVA)/AV5/AV25<br/>
24/04/16 12:00 CET FUTBOL: LEVANTE-ATHLETIC CLUB (ESPAÑA/LIGA BBVA)/AV1/AV2/AV21/AV22<br/>
24/04/16 16:00 CET FUTBOL: SEVILLA-REAL BETIS (ESPAÑA/LIGA BBVA)/AV1/AV2/AV21/AV22<br/>
24/04/16 18:15 CET FUTBOL: GETAFE-VALENCIA (ESPAÑA/LIGA BBVA)/AV1/AV2/AV21/AV22<br/>
24/04/16 20:30 CET FUTBOL: VILLARREAL-REAL SOCIEDAD (ESPAÑA/LIGA BBVA)/AV1/AV2/AV21/AV22<br/>
```

but when I call function from other site, I get:

```
prueba = obtener_canales()
print prueba
```

< / html >

Comment: You're function is not returning anything...

Comment: Would you like for `obtener_canales()` to return an HTML string containing all of the items that are currently being printed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function does not return anything, it just prints. If you want to use function `obtener_canales` as a data provider, it shout return data.

```
def obtener_canales():
    for i in range (1,3):
        url = "http://arenavision.in/agenda"
        peticion = urllib2.Request(url, headers={'User-Agent' : "Magic Browser"})
        leemos_page = urllib2.urlopen(peticion)
        enlace_acestream = leemos_page.read()
        leemos_page.close()
    partido = enlace_acestream
    for item in partido.split("\n"):
        if "LIGA BBVA" in item:
              print item
    return partido
```

Comment: Im learning, sorry and thank you!!

Comment: No problem. Good luck! :)